# Google fonts not displaying on live site

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I recently did an update to the code I'm working on for a website and for some reason Google fonts have stopped working on the site

http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/simple.html

I don't want to copy and paste all the code in as there's quite a lot. Anyone else having this problem just now or is there an error somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you add a text CV in your style.css, remove it.

```
CV@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:300;
}
```

Comment: i am.

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-weight:300;
}

Comment: Removing the CV fixed it.... absolutely no idea where that has come from.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the font before the `style.css`, **switch this**

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
```

**to:**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Im already doing that.

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-weight:300;
}

Comment: @Gezzamondo also remove `CV@charset "UTF-8";` from your `style.css`

Answer (score 0):

When working with google fonts replace their single marks with double quoutemarks and if you're working on a local server make sure the http:// is included when linking.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem just remove http:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
```